# Why git identity is keep losing with bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

Whenever I need to `git pull` or `git push` repo on bitbucket.org on Win10 dev laptop, almost every time I need to add the identity before I can do that. Here is the `ssh -T`:

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Then after `eval "$(ssh-agent)` and `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, I can `git pull` or `git push`. Next time I need to repeat the process again. Why the identity is keep losing? How can I add the identity once for all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good start is to understand the steps you are doing and how `ssh-agent` works or how you can do that better.

SSH-Agent is a program storing your private key in the memory and to save you from typing passphrase for every connection. Your shell remembers the connection to this program using environment variables. So if you open new shell run `ssh-agent` and close the shell, you lose this connection (Windows does not have this anyhow integrated). Also restarting computer (obviously) stops the running agent.

But you might use

```
$ ssh -T -i /path/to/id_rsa git@bitbucket.org
```

which will do the same (you will have to insert passphrase if you have one). Or more cleanly using `ssh_config` in `~/.ssh/config`, which can contain:

```
Host bitbucket.org
  User git
  IdentityFile /path/to/id_rsa
```

and then connecting using

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
```

will work too.