# SSH asking every single time for passphrase

Tags: git, github, ssh, terminal, git-tower

I have an annoying problem with my private key. Every time I want to `clone` or `push` via ssh in terminal or Tower app, I have to type my passphrase.

I even removed and recreated the ssh key and set the key on Github several times, but it looks like it has a short lifetime and after a couple of minutes, is expired!

I followed [generate a new SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) to create the key. At the end I ran `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and it printed out:

```
Identity added: /Users/sajad/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/sajad/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

After I restarted my machine I ran `ssh-add -l` to check whether it's still there or not and here is the result:

```
The agent has no identities.
```

How can I fix this? I use macOS.

My `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
#   $OpenBSD: ssh_config,v 1.30 2016/02/20 23:06:23 sobrado Exp $

# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
        SendEnv LANG LC_*

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a different theory. Please review.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why git identity is keep losing with bitbucket repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034394/why-git-identity-is-keep-losing-with-bitbucket-repo)

Comment: Found this link handy:
https://gist.github.com/danieldogeanu/16c61e9b80345c5837b9e5045a701c99

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Ensure you are actually using SSH

This really sounds like your remote is not using SSH at all, but is using HTTP. In that case, every time you use the remote, it will ask you to authenticate.

You can check this by looking at your remote URLs. For SSH you want it to look like this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:yourUsername/yourRepo (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:yourUsername/yourRepo (push)
```

If you are using HTTP, then it will instead look like this:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/yourUsername/yourRepo.git (push)
```

If you find it is set to use HTTP, it's easy to change.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:yourUsername/yourRepo
```

### SSH key asking for passphrase every time it is used

If it turns out that you are already using SSH, you should check your SSH configuration. There are two locations to check on a Mac.

- `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`
- `/Users/{your_username}/.ssh/config`

In particular, you do not want this setting:

```
AddKeysToAgent confirm
```

From the ssh_config man page:

> ```
> AddKeysToAgent
>    Specifies whether keys should be automatically added to a running
>    ssh-agent(1).  If this option is set to ``yes'' and a key is
>    loaded from a file, the key and its passphrase are added to the
>    agent with the default lifetime, as if by ssh-add(1).  If this
>    option is set to ``ask'', ssh will require confirmation using the
>    SSH_ASKPASS program before adding a key (see ssh-add(1) for
>    details).  If this option is set to ``confirm'', each use of the
>    key must be confirmed, as if the -c option was specified to
>    ssh-add(1).  If this option is set to ``no'', no keys are added
>    to the agent.  The argument must be ``yes'', ``confirm'',
>    ``ask'', or ``no''.  The default is ``no''.
> ```

And this is a description of the `-c` flag to `ssh-add`:

> ```
> -c      Indicates that added identities should be subject to confirmation
>         before being used for authentication.  Confirmation is performed
>         by ssh-askpass(1).  Successful confirmation is signaled by a zero
>         exit status from ssh-askpass(1), rather than text entered into
>         the requester.
> ```

### SSH key not present in agent at startup

After you restart the machine, the key being gone is normal. You have to add it at least once after the machine starts up.

Comment: I set `AddKeysToAgent confirm` in the .ssh/config and it doesn't work.

Comment: @SajadAbedi I wasn't suggesting you add it. I was suggesting it sounded like your problem was caused by it. Did you also look at `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`?

Comment: @DanLowe Do you know how to get `AddKeysToAgent confirm` to work? I was expecting to see an admin dialog for confirmation, but instead I kept getting `agent refused operation` error. I'm interested in `confirm` mode to minimize the chances of a malware abusing my SSH keys in the background w/o my knowledge. (I'm on a Mac btw)

Comment: @Unknown sorry, I don't know. I'm also on Mac and I get the same result. Doing some searching I don't see any information about it.

Comment: @DanLowe Thank you for taking the time and confirming. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 14):

There's some really good solutions to a very similar question over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1127067/macos-keeps-asking-my-ssh-passphrase-since-i-updated-to-sierra) and [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots).

The basic gist is that Apple recently changed some of these behaviours in Sierra. Thankfully, it's simple to get them back by adding the following to the top of your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

That should be enough to get it to start using the keychain to store/retrieve your SSH key passphrase.

Comment: I have `AddKeysToAgent` but not `UseKeychain`, and works for me here. I have to use the passphrase once per key after a reboot or logout/login, but I do not have to use them every time. (I prefer not to store them in keychain - entering them once after bootup is fine with me)

Answer (score 1):

```
# ~/.ssh/config:
AddKeysToAgent yes

# you should also add "-t" to ssh-agent startup to forget decrypted keys
# after some time (here: 1 hour, overridden by ssh-add - in case you really
# need to use some keys all the time)
# ~/.bashrc:
if ! pidof /usr/bin/ssh-agent >/dev/null; then
  ssh-agent -t 3600 > ~/.ssh/.agent.pid
fi
source ~/.ssh/.agent.pid >&/dev/null
```