# Force git to use specific key.pub

Tags: git, ssh-keys

I have to keys in ~/.ssh dir.
When I am trying to commit something in console bitbucket is asking me for password instead use ssh key.
Also when I try to clone this repo in order to use global git settings it is still asking me for password.

My questions:

- how to config git to use ssh keys?
- how to force it?
- which key it is trying to use?
- is it trying to much it by email? (if yes than is it using mail from global config or local repository config?)
- can I use ssh key without additional password, or is it required to have one?

Comment: Is the key added to your `ssh-agent` as per https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent ? Is the public key added to your BitBucket account?

Comment: Well, it sounds like you have a passphrase on the key. That will be required every time you use that key pair.

Comment: No! Bitbucket is asking me for its password.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131834/discussion-between-gkucmierz-and-jack-maney).

Comment: If you happen to be on a Mac that you recently updated to Sierra, you should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41287226/ssh-asking-every-single-time-for-passphrase/41287392#comment69777996_41287392).

Answer (score 10):

To make GIT use a specific SSH key, you prefix the GIT command with

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i <path-to-key>"
```

Where "path-to-key" is the path to the private SSH key (without the ".pub").

So if you would like to clone from git://random-address and your public key is in /home/me/.ssh/mysecondkey.pub, you run:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/mysecondkey" git clone git://random-address
```

You need to make sure that you choose a clone-URL which does not start with "https://", but either "ssh://" or "git://". I know at least GitHub lets you choose which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following as I had the same problem about specifying a specific public key for some repository:

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475646/using-git-ssh-command-in-git-for-windows) answer: you can add a configuration per repository as to what `ssh` command the `git` client uses. If you want a specific ssh-key used you can do:

```
git config --local core.sshCommand 'ssh -i <path-to-key>'
```

Then git will use that command, and thus that key to authenticate with the remote.